# $cookie gets data not as Map but as String

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

Here is my Javascript.

```
app.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, $cookies) {

$scope.registerInfo = {};

if($cookies.registerInfo){
angular.forEach($cookies.registerInfo, function(value, key) {
    $scope.registerInfo[key] = value;
});
}

$scope.preserve = function() {
    $cookies.registerInfo = new Map();
    angular.forEach($scope.registerInfo, function(value, key) {
        $cookies.registerInfo.set(key, value);
    });
};
```

I already set HTML including the code below.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="registerInfo.lunch_budget_from">
<input type="number" ng-model="registerInfo.lunch_budget_to">
<button ng-click="preserve();">
```

What I want do is to save data as Map on cookie, but '$cookies.registerInfo' is saved as String and I can't get the value correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are always strings, no objects, If you want to store an object in a cookie, you need to serialize / deserialize the object:

```
app.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, $cookies) {

$scope.registerInfo = {};

if($cookies.registerInfo){
    $scope.registerInfo = JSON.parse($cookies.registerInfo);
}

$scope.preserve = function() {
    var registerInfo = new Map();
    angular.forEach($scope.registerInfo, function(value, key) {
        registerInfo.set(key, value);
    });
    $cookies.registerInfo = JSON.stringify(registerInfo);
};
```

The only constraint with this is, that cookies may not exceed a length of 1K Bytes, including name and value. Probably you may look for localStorage, which also gives you the ability to store objects w/o serializing/deserializing

Important: before testing this, old cookies may have to be deleted.

Comment: Thanks, but $cookies does not save anything when I execute the code. I confirmed 'registerInfo.set(key, value)' correctly sets key and value to registerInfo. So, probably JSON.stringify works wrong.  Btw, how can I notice 'Cookies are always strings, no objects' ? When I searched $cookies on Angular official page, it does not describe any explanation like this. Or is it too apparent to write down on the website? I'm sorry I'm a newbie for programming.

Comment: I just found JSON.stringify is not executable for Map because of key-type issue. Check https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787011. I solved this issue, simply changing Map to an Array.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting value by using dot notation, have you tried to use get() method

```
var registerInfo = $cookies.get('registerInfo');
```

More info for $cookies service

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: As I'm using ionic, my angular.js version is 1.3.13. I can't use 'get' method.

Comment: Can you try to use JSON.parse() to turn string back to an object?

Comment: I got 'Error:Unexpected token u' when I implemented JSON.parse($cookies.registerInfo).